# Wifi keeps stalling

Tags: networking, wireless

O.S. Ubuntu 16.04. Every few minutes i have to disable end re-enable wifi through nm. i have to keep doing this as long as I am online. Wifi says connected but I get no network traffic unless I disable and re-enable wifi. I've searched google for this problem but all I get are responses with the older ubuntu versions. i don't know if this matters or not but I have laptop Samsung R780. All original parts.

More information.
The results are at this link paste.ubuntu.com/24252415

Comment: Please see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205

Comment: You haven't properly read the question/answer, please do and add the information given by the script described in the accepted answer.

Comment: The results are at this link http://paste.ubuntu.com/24252415/

Comment: I reran the code when I had wifi issues. Keep in mind wifi shows connected on NM and the wifi signal shows strong. But as you can see below there was no network.

--2017-03-26 02:57:23--  https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.253.113, 192.30.253.112
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.253.113|:443... failed: Connection timed out.

Comment: I turned on echo when booting to see if I could see any problems and I found a problem. 14.3678521 rt1819xe 0000:02:00.0 wlan0 (uninitialized): _rt192e_read_eeprom_ info(): Invalid EEPROM ID: 4a4.

Comment: This error is interesting to me because on startup I do have connected wifi. I dodn't have to do anything. It just does not stay connected for very long.